Python "r+" mode reads nothing after writing with Pickle library
I have a file that I want to read a list from and then write an updated list to it by using the pickle library. But after that it reads nothing from the file. I have tried using other people's examples, even copy-pasted some, but I cannot get it to work.
I am using Windows 10 and am aware of the bug that was mentioned in similar questions. The solution I got from those questions was to add f.seek(f.tell()) before writing, but that does not work when I'm writing with the pickle library.
Here's what I have:
import pickle

with open("data.bin", "r+b") as file:
    temp_data = pickle.load(file)
    temp_data.append("test")
    file.seek(file.tell())
    pickle.dump(temp_data, file)

with open("data.bin", "rb") as file:
    print(pickle.load(file))
    # prints empty list

If I read and write separately, then it does work. But I should be able to use r+ right? (I have also tried all this with a regular text file in case it had to do with binary mode, but I got the same results.)
import pickle

temp_data = []

with open("data.bin", "rb") as file:
    temp_data = pickle.load(file)

with open("data.bin", "wb") as file:
    temp_data.append("test")
    pickle.dump(temp_data, file)

with open("data.bin", "rb") as file:
    print(pickle.load(file))
    # prints ['test']

Does anyone know why this happens, or do I just have to do it separately?

That's what r+ does: it opens the file and positions the cursor at the start, so if you don't first seek to the end of the file that new data overwrites what's already there. However, the way you do that is not by seeking to file.tell(): that just places the cursor to where it already is, because file.tell() gives you the current position. You want to seek to the end of the file.

Effectively this problem stems from not knowing the details of the file mode you were using, which is covered over in Difference between modes a, a+, w, w+, and r+ in built-in open function.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The file mode I'm using wasn't the problem. I know the difference. It works now by using file.seek(0). I expected that since w overwrites everything, that I wouldn't need to move the cursor.

Then you need to [edit] your post to be more clear, because when I read "If I open data.bin in notepad, there is something there. However if I run this multiple times, only the last thing that was appended is in the file." what that tells me is that your file only contains the last run's data. Which is exactly what you'd expect given the use of a+b. At the very least, please update your post to show a [mcve] (because as is, even touching data.bin means your code can't run yet, pickle will throw on an empty file).

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That was not my question though. I added it because I thought it was interesting that it doesn't print anything even though there was something. I solved it now by changing the seek. I'll remove it to prevent future confusion.

updated my answer to more strictly stick to your question.

Remember that both reading and writing by definition moves the file handle's position to the end of the file, so you need to set that back to zero every time you intend to "do more pickle related things later":
import os, pickle

fname = "data.bin"
data = ["test"]

if not os.path.isfile(fname):
    with open(fname, "wb") as file:
        pickle.dump(data, file)
        file.close()
    print(f"{fname} created")

with open(fname, "r+b") as file:
    # load our file and reset the file pointer for future pickles
    data = pickle.load(file)
    file.seek(0)

    print("data read:", data)

    # update our data...
    data.append(f"test-{len(data)}")
    print("updated data:", data)

    # ...then write that back, again resetting the file pointer afterwards
    pickle.dump(data, file)
    file.seek(0)

    # then let's load that back in, still remembering that file pointer
    data = pickle.load(file)
    file.seek(0)

    print("reloaded data:", data)

    # ...and then the rest of what you need to do...

Running this three times:
(venv) D:\temp>python test.py       
data.bin created
data read: ['test']
updated data: ['test', 'test-1']
reloaded data: ['test', 'test-1']

(venv) D:\temp>python test.py
data read: ['test', 'test-1']
updated data: ['test', 'test-1', 'test-2']
reloaded data: ['test', 'test-1', 'test-2']

(venv) D:\temp>python test.py
data read: ['test', 'test-1', 'test-2']
updated data: ['test', 'test-1', 'test-2', 'test-3']
reloaded data: ['test', 'test-1', 'test-2', 'test-3']


This is essentially the alternative solution I stated in my question. You're opening a file 2 times in r+ mode while only either reading or writing in each one. The point of r+ is that you can read and write while only needing to open a file once. The only extra step I'm doing while the file is open, is appending new data.

True. Updated the anwer to stay in the same file even though that's generally not great practice: if you absolutely need the same file handle, then remember to reset the file pointer after each read or write.
